# Is traditional negative binomial regression robust to model misspecification or not?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, robust, misspecification

By "traditional" NBR I mean NB2, i.e. the one modeling variance as a quadratic function of the mean, with the formula: $Var(Y)=E[Y]*(1+\alpha*E[Y])$. I have found contrasting statements in the literature. Here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23776062/
I read in the Abstract: "adjusting for covariates raises concerns about model misspecification, in which the negative binomial regression is not robust because of its requirement for strong model assumptions". Instead, here:
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epub/10.1080/00031305.2018.1564699?needAccess=true
I read that this problem only arises with NB1, following the formula: $Var(Y)=E[Y]*(1+\alpha)$, i.e. with variance proportional to the mean, as in the quasiPoisson/Poisson with robust standard errors.
I find the same inconsistency in statistical forums: at the opposite extremes, those who say "If you have overdispersion, go for NBR" and those saying: "If you are only interested in estimating conditional means, go for a Poisson regression with robust SEs". Then, there are intermediate positions, as suggesting to compare the two models before choosing, or to try the Poisson with robust SEs first (and only if it's not fulfilling go for the NBR).

What is the truth about NBR robustness to model misspecification?